# Add new shipping method in NopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to add new shipping methods in the Shipping step, during check out process. Where in Admin section should I add them? And How? So far I tried in Config > Shipping > Shipping Methods section. But it didn't help me.

Comment: Which shipping method? Do you have any plugin for that or you want to develop shipping method plugin..make it clear

Comment: I don't want to develop any plugin. I want to use these shipping methods US Mail, FedEx Standard Overnite, FedEx 2 Day, FedEx Ground Service

Comment: Okay, you can see it at admin > configuration > shipping > shipping provider. You can see it on demo [here](http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/Shipping/Providers). Do you have plugins for all?

Comment: I figured that out. Now I can see FedEx options in the Select shipping method page. But I don't see the USPS Standard Post option. I made it active and also selected the Standard Post option in configuration

Comment: Are you talking about `USPS (US Postal Service)` plugin?

Comment: Yes it is not showing up. I logged out and log back in as well. Do you want to move to chat room?

Answer (score 1):

You have to develop new Plugin for your new shipping Method. If you cannot find your desired shipping method in the nopcommerce marketplace. Once you develop plugin you have to install and then there will be your shipping method in in the checkout screen.